# Asp.net core not binding values from Jquery post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

First off I am learning Asp.net core. I have a View as follows, when I the blogItemId I retrieve an item and send it as a model to the `DetailedView.cshtml` as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DetailedView(int blogItemId)
{
    var item = _mainBlogHelperModel.BlogDataItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == blogItemId);

    if (item == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("MainBlog", new { page = 1, blogCategory = "" });
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

Now in the `DetailedView.cshtml`, I have a form. When I click the "Post Comment" button within the form, I would like to save some model record within the database and update some section with in the view.

Problem number 1: Please see my Model class below, I have a navigation property and foreign key. How do I specify these values within jQuery from my Model.

Problem number 2: I have a breakpoint in the `PostComment` method, but jQuery is not binding any values. Everything is null. please help.

Here is my `DetailedView.cshtml`:

```
@model KGSBlog.Models.BlogData

@SOME CODE HERE @

<form id="formPostComment" method="post" action="BlogData/PostComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email *" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="WebSite" name="website">
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message *" id="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>

    <button id="btnPostComment" class="btn btn-main m-bottom-40">Post Comment</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {   
     <!-- jQuery -->
     <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Components Plugin -->
     <script src="~/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
            $("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();

                var dataToPost = {};
                dataToPost.Name = name;
                dataToPost.Email = email;
                dataToPost.Comment = message;
                //How can I populate the BlogId and Blog properties here?

               $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("PostComment", "BlogData")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //do stuff with json result
                    },
                    error: function(passParams) {
                        console.log("Error is " + passParams);
                    }
               });
            });
        });
        </script>
}
```

Here is my `BlogDataController` `PostComment` action method where the properties in the `blogComment` parameter are all null.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment(BlogComments blogComment)
{
    if (blogComment != null)
    {
        await _context.BlogComments.AddAsync(blogComment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    var item = _mainBlogHelperModel.BlogDataItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == blogComment.Id);
    return new JsonResult(new { comment = blogComment.Comment, name = blogComment.Name });
}
```

The `BlogComments` model class

```
public class BlogComments
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BlogID")]
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public BlogData Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem number 1: Ideally, you don't want to pass the `Blog` property, you just want to pass the `BlogId`. It's not causing your issue but in my opinion, you shouldn't use the entity as the model, you should have another class that acts as a DTO. [Is it good practice to use entity objects as data transfer objects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350067/is-it-good-practice-to-use-entity-objects-as-data-transfer-objects)

You can do what you're looking for with something like this:

```
dataToPost.BlogId = @Model.Id;
```

Problem number 2: It might be fixed after you've resolved problem number 1. The problem might be that your action is expecting an `int` for `BlogId` but you're currently not passing `BlogId`.

If that doesn't work, open the network tab in the browser and make sure it's passing the POST body. Then check for `ModelState` errors in your action to see if any of the properties are failing validation.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your original post  you were  using contentType: "application/json", you just needed to add a [FromBody] attribute and everything would be working

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromBody]BlogComments blogComment)
```

in your second post the code is working because in this case your content type is form-data (by default). In this case you don't neeed  [FromBody] attribute

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats the difference between what I wrote and this, except for some attributes, but i changed the jquery code as follows, after referring to this [post](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-AJAX-Form-Submit-Post-Example.aspx) and it works. If someone can tell me why my old code was not working and this one is working, that will be great. (May be I shouldn't stringify the object)

First off I made the form like this,

```
<form id="formPostComment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="PostComment" asp-controller="BlogData">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" id="name" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email *" id="email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="WebSite" name="website">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <textarea placeholder="Message *" id="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>

                                <submit id="btnPostComment" class="btn btn-main m-bottom-40">Post Comment</button>

                            </form>
@This is the jquery code.@

 @section Scripts{


        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
                var url = $("#formPostComment").attr("action");
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("Name", $("#name").val());
                formData.append("Email", $("#email").val());
                formData.append("Comment", $("#message").val());
                formData.append("BlogId",@Model.Id);

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response.Status === "Success") {
                    alert("HELLO");
                }
            });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The Controller code, I just changed the parameter like this. Even with the old jquery code, I tried Bind like this and it didn't work.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([Bind("Name,Email,Comment,BlogId")] BlogComments blogComment)
```

Comment: Have a look at [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute-1) to know the difference between [FromForm] and [FromBody] in Asp.Net Core.

Comment: Thank You so much have I read your post earlier I wouldn't have posted this,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034769/asp-net-core-load-partial-view-from-jquery-on-click?noredirect=1#comment130721425_74034769